# Ruby on rails, ajax, offset, limit. undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to do something like link "More". But i get error in my view "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"

Controller

```
WHO_IS_OUT_LIST_PER_PAGE = 6

def show_who_is_out_list
    @offset = params[:offset].to_i
    get_who_is_out_list
    render 'show_who_is_out_list', layout: false
  end

private
    def get_who_is_out_list
      data = current_company.time_off_requests.page(@offset, WHO_IS_OUT_LIST_PER_PAGE)
      @offset = (data.length < WHO_IS_OUT_LIST_PER_PAGE) ? nil : @offset + WHO_IS_OUT_LIST_PER_PAGE
      @who_is_out_list = data
    end
```

In model I have a scope

```
scope :page, ->(offset, limit) { order("start_date desc").limit(limit).offset(offset) }
```

In view show_who_is_out_list - js

```
:plain
  $("#who-is-out").html("#{escape_javascript(render 'who_is_out')}");
```

And this is the partial with error

```
%header.box-header-title.clearfix
  %h1.header-h1 Who’s out?
  %a.box-header-link{:href => "/time_off_requests/manage"} View Calendar
%ul.list.sidebar-list
  %li.clearfix
  - @who_is_out_list.each do |t|
    %td= t.user.full_name
    -if (t.start_date == t.end_date and t.start_date >= Date.today)
      %span= t.start_date.strftime("%b %d")
      %br
    -else
      %span= "#{t.start_date.strftime("%b %d")}"' - '"#{t.end_date.strftime("%b %d")}"
      %br
  %li.clearfix
    = link_to t('Back'), show_who_is_out_list_path(offset: 0), remote: true, class: 'btn'
    - if @offset.present?
      = link_to t('next'), show_who_is_out_list_path(offset: @offset), remote: true, class: 'btn'
```

routes

```
resource :time_off_request, only: :all do
    get 'show_who_is_out_list'
  end
```

What's wrong? I'm almost junior RoR dev and i must write it with ajax( Can you help me?

Comment: what line is the error occurring on?  and what does `data` return?  are you sure it's definitely returning something (ie, there's not an error in the definition of either `data` or `@offset`)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the problem here is with `@who_is_out_list = data` since you're only calling `each` on that.

try this:

```
@who_is_out_list = data if data.exists?
```

Comment: it not help( undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass